# ItoProcess function

Tags: finance, stochastic-calculus, random-process

While looking in the help manual of Mathematica concerning the ItoProcess function I found the following:

ItoProcess[{a,b,c},x,t]: represents an Ito Process **y(t)=c(t,x(t))**, where **dx(t)=a(t,x(t))dt+b(t,x(t)).dw(t)**

In order to replicate and Plot this, I entered the following code:

```
(*Defining a process y(t)=c((xt)), where \[DifferentialD]x(t)=μ\
\[DifferentialD]t+σ\[DifferentialD]w(t)*)

ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[
    t] == μ \[DifferentialD]t + σ \[DifferentialD]w[t], 
 c[x[t]], {x, 0}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
```

Then I wanted to Plot one process by implementing drift and volatility.

```
(*Simulation of one Ito Process with μ=0.1 and σ=0.2, \
starting value x=0*)

testprocess5 = 
 ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == 
   0.1 *\[DifferentialD]t + 0.2 *\[DifferentialD]w[t],
c[x[t]], {x, 0}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
```

Concerning this code I got the same output like in the Mathematica help manual just the drift and the volatility were substituted by 0.1 and 0.2 respectively.

However, when I tried to plot the process it did not work out.

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[RandomFunction[
    testprocess5, {0 (*startis from t=0*), 5 (*ends at t=5*), 
     0.01 (*Δt*)}] ["Path"], {1(*number of paths*)}], 
 Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"time", "value"}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

I am not sure, why it is not workling, maybe it could be due to y (t) = c ((xt)).
Does anyone of you have a solution for this problem or a suggestion how to change the code?

thanks

Comment: Does your `Table` produce a set of numbers? If not, then it probably won't plot...

Comment: @cormullion No,I get the following error: RandomFunction::unsproc: The specification ItoProcess[True,c[x[t]],{x,0},t,w\[Distributed]WienerProcess[0,1]] is not a random process recognized by the system. >> ; but if I use this: testprocess3 = 
 ItoProcess[{0.5(*\[Mu]*), 0.2(*\[Sigma]*)}, {x, 0 (*condition that x=
   0 at t=0*)}, t] and ListLinePlot[
 Table[RandomFunction[
    testprocess3, {0 (*startis from t=0*), 5 (*ends at t=5*), 
     0.01 (*\[CapitalDelta]t*)}] ["Path"], {1(*number of paths*)}], 
 Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"time", "value"}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotRange -> All], why ???

Comment: Try starting a new Mathematica session and then post the minimal example code that you think should work and that others can run - I think you're encountering problems because you have definitions still in the kernel...

Comment: @cormullion I tried it, but its still not working, although I get a table now. but there is still the constant c in front of the y-coordinates. have you tried it? does it work when you run the code?

Comment: Exactly - the table is full of c[...]'s so I can't see how it could be be plotted by `ListLinePlot`. Further than that I don't (can't) go... :)

Comment: @MilanIvica May I ask you where did you get this function? I believe the function is not correctly defined, once its Mean and Variance cannot be computed. Try, for instance, `Mean[testprocess5[t]]` and `Variance[testprocess5[t]]`... I keep getting wrong results...

Comment: Maybe `c` is not defined ? Can you try substituting `c` with `Exp` in your `testprocess5` ?

Comment: @Rod Lm its when you look in Mathematica9 for ItoProcess and the second explanation. And then look please at basic uses and there is the function defined. There is written: Use the differential notation to define the same process: ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[
    t] == \[Mu] \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma] \[DifferentialD]w[t], 
 c[x[t]], {x, 0}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]

Comment: @b.gatessucks Hi, if i substitute c with Exp it works. Can you explain me why? Is then the deffinition of the process correct? At least, when I plot it, it looks correct. but I am not sure

Comment: @MilanIvica I think you need to have an explicit definition of the output expression, `c` in your case; typically, you define the process for `x[t]` whereas your price is `Exp[x[t]]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks now I get it...thank you :-)

Comment: @b.gatessucks I have one more question. do you have any Idea how to implement a correlated wiener process in this function. e.g. If I have a Index and a lets say company. So the index is driven by an ItoProcess and its individual WienerProcess, whereas the company value is driven by also a ItoProcess but the underlying Wiener process consists of a indivudual component and a componed that is correlated to the Index Wiener Process?

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation, there are several examples about it.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I had a look at it. especially under the subtitles" Define a process drven by two correlated wiener processes" whereas I am not sure how I can distinguish between the two processes. I also lokked under "Define a process corrsponding to the 2D correlated Wiener Process"; however I do not understand it totally; what exactly is the theta in the function and n1 and n2 are they the corresponding two processes and I thing s and r are the two different variables. do you know any manual or tutorial concerning this, where Mathematica explains everything? thanks

Comment: @MilanIvica Do you need to generate 2 correlated processes, right? Did you take a look at [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27068/share-experiences-preferably-the-surprising-ones-with-using-itoprocess)?

Comment: @ Rod Lm Yes I did. it's interesting

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure if I correctly understood what you want... However, I could read in the question that you want to simulate Ito Processes and, at the same time, to be able to change its parameters, especially the processes **drifts** and **volatilities**. In the comments I've read about the processes being **correlated**, so, let me try to put everything together in this answer...

**First:** set all the parameters you want to simulate;

```
iv1 = 1; (* initial value for process 1 *)
iv2 = -1; (* initial value for process 2 *)
drift1 = 0; (* drift of process 1 *)
drift2 = 0; (* drift of process 2 *)
diffusion1 = .2; (* diffusion of process 1 *)
diffusion2 = .2; (* diffusion of process 2 *)
correl = 0; (* Set the correlation value here *)
covar = correl*Sqrt[diffusion1]*Sqrt[diffusion2]; (* don't touch here! *)
```

**Second:** define the 2D-process;

```
proc = ItoProcess[{{drift1, drift2}, {{diffusion1, covar}, {covar, diffusion2}}}, {{w1,w2}, {iv1, iv2}}, t];
```

**Third:** compute the 2D-process means and variances;

```
processmean[x_] = Mean[proc[t]]; // Quiet
processvariance[x_] = Variance[proc[t]]; // Simplify // Quiet
```

**Fourth:** show the *theoretical* path intervals

```
G1 = Show[Plot[{processmean[t] - 2 Sqrt[processvariance[t]], processmean[t] + 2 Sqrt[processvariance[t]], processmean[t]}, {t, 0, 20}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Fifth:** generate the **k** desired amount of random paths;

```
k = 10; (* amount of paths to be generated for each individual process *)
path = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 20}, k]
```

**Sixth:** see the paths you've generated;

```
G2 = ListLinePlot[path["PathComponent", 1], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thin, Lighter@Red}]]
G3 = ListLinePlot[path["PathComponent", 2], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thin, Lighter@Green}]]
```

[image]
[image]

**Seventh:** show everything together;

```
Show[G2,G3,G1]
```

[image]

## Correlation bug

According to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27068/share-experiences-preferably-the-surprising-ones-with-using-itoprocess) there is a known bug affecting 2D-correlated Ito Processes. However, in my simulations I couldn't find any problem when generating correlated processes.

Consider, for instance, the 2D-process. In order to visualize the correlated processes I'll use the extrem case of a high negative correlation between the processes ($\rho=-0.95$). I'll also generate only two paths for better visualization/understanding.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
iv1 = 1;
iv2 = 1;
drift1 = 0;
drift2 = 0;
diffusion1 = .2;
diffusion2 = .2;
correl = -.95; (* Set correlation here *)
covar = correl*Sqrt[diffusion1]*Sqrt[diffusion2];
proc = ItoProcess[{{drift1, drift2}, {{diffusion1, covar}, {covar, diffusion2}}}, {{w1, w2}, {iv1, iv2}}, t];
k = 2;
path = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 20}, k]
```

Now you can visually observe the negative relationship between the generated processes:

```
G5 = ListLinePlot[path["PathComponent", 1], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Lighter@Red}]]
G6 = ListLinePlot[path["PathComponent", 2], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Lighter@Green}]]
```

[image]
[image]

You might also want to see them all together with theoretical paths:

```
processmean[x_] = Mean[proc[t]]; // Quiet
processvariance[x_] = Variance[proc[t]]; // Simplify // Quiet
G7 = Show[Plot[{processmean[t] - 2 Sqrt[processvariance[t]], processmean[t] + 2 Sqrt[processvariance[t]], processmean[t]}, {t, 0, 20}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}], PlotRange -> All];
Show[G5, G6, G7]
```

[image]

I hope this will help you.

**EDITED**

Another example of negative-correlated processes, this time with positive drifts.

```
iv1 = 1;
iv2 = 1;
drift1 = .1;
drift2 = .3;
diffusion1 = .15;
diffusion2 = .25;
correl = -.95; (* Set correlation here *)
covar = correl*Sqrt[diffusion1]*Sqrt[diffusion2];
proc = ItoProcess[{{drift1, drift2}, {{diffusion1, covar}, {covar, diffusion2}}}, {{w1, w2}, {iv1, iv2}}, t];
processmean[x_] = Mean[proc[t]]; // Quiet
processvariance[x_] = Variance[proc[t]]; // Simplify // Quiet
G8 = Show[Plot[{processmean[t] - 2 Sqrt[processvariance[t]], processmean[t] + 2 Sqrt[processvariance[t]], processmean[t]}, {t, 0, 20}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}], PlotRange -> All]
k = 1;
path = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 20}, k]
G9 = ListLinePlot[path["PathComponent", 1], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Lighter@Red}]]
G10 = ListLinePlot[path["PathComponent", 2], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Lighter@Green}]]
Show[G8, G9, G10]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I admire you, seriously. I can't thank you enough for your help and support :) this is really cool stuff!