# Solve ItoProcess SDE

Tags: stochastic-calculus, random

I specified a SDE for a random process $y(t)$ using `ItoProcess` is there a mathematica function that provides the analytic solution for $y(t)$? I know `Mean[]` and `CovarianceFunction[]` but they do not provide the analytic solution.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't Mathematics.SE -- If you are having trouble with the mathematics behind a concept you are on the wrong side of town.

Comment: I am asking for a mathematica function. I removed the other question to resolve the confusion.

Comment: It seems the link on the [right here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27110/1089) does exactly what you want?

Comment: @chris I think not as the link does only explain how to simulate but not how to solve an ItoProcess

Comment: What's wrong with 4th : show the theoretical path intervals?

Comment: I might be missing something obvious here but I don't see an analytical expression for the process in 4th.

Comment: `{processmean[t],processvariance[t]}` are analytic AFAIK?

Comment: But only if we assume that the process is a gaussian process right? Otherwise the mean and the covariance function might not describe the process fully