# Simulating a bivariate Ito process

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I would like to simulate a bivariate process where the two components, say $X_1(t) $ and $ X_2(t), $ which are related by the following stochastic differential equations:

```
dX_1(t) = -X_2(t)dt + \sigma_1dW^{(1)}(t)  
and
dX_2(t) = X_1(t)dt + \sigma_2dW^{(2)}(t).
```

I would also like to allow the two BMs $W^{(1)} $ and $W^{(2)} $ that are correlated.

What would be the proper way to do this by defining a process using **ItoProcess** first and then simulating it via **RandomFunction**? If the coefficients were just a function of $t $ and not of $X_i(t, $ then I am able to make it work, but everytime I try to enter the process as described in the two SDEs above, I get some error message to the tone that "process" does not exist.

Any help much appreciated. I tried to make sense of what Mathematica has for explanation in the online help, but it does not seem to solve my issues.

Thank you.

Maurice

Comment: Maybe a starting point [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27110/134).

Comment: I was already aware of that thread. It works fine, but as long as my drifts and diffusions are not functions of the processes involved themselves. I do believe that what I did is a modification of that, but alas, cannot get it to work in my setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could define a process:

```
proc[x10_, x20_, \[Sigma]1_, \[Sigma]2_, \[Rho]_] := 
 ItoProcess[{
 \[DifferentialD]x1[t] == -x2[t]\[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma]1 \[DifferentialD]Wa[t], 
 \[DifferentialD]x2[t] == x1[t]  \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma]2 (\[Rho] \[DifferentialD]Wa[t] + Sqrt[1 - \[Rho]^2] \[DifferentialD]Wb[t])}, 
 {x1[t], x2[t]}, {{x1, x2}, {x10, x20}}, {t, 0}, 
 {Wa \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], Wb \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}]
```

and then use it:

```
Mean[proc[x10, x20, \[Sigma]1, \[Sigma]2, \[Rho]][t]]
(* {x10 Cos[t] - x20 Sin[t], x20 Cos[t] + x10 Sin[t]} *)
```

This matches the analytical result:

$$x_1(t)=-\imath\ (y_1(t)-y_2(t))$$
$$x_2(t)=y_1(t)+y_2(t)$$
$$y_1(t)=e^{-\imath\ t}\left[ y_1(0)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{t}\ e^{\imath\ \tau}\ \left(\imath\ \sigma_1 dW_a\ +\ \sigma_2 dW_b \right)\right]$$
$$y_2(t)=e^{\imath\ t}\left[ y_2(0)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{t}\ e^{-\imath\ \tau}\ \left(-\imath\ \sigma_1 dW_a\ +\ \sigma_2 dW_b \right)\right]$$

Other properties (covariance, ...) could be checked along the same lines.

Comment: That is excellent. Thank you.